# Changing widget type of field by using PyQGIS

Tags: fields-attributes, pyqgis-3, widget

I'm working on a plugin for QGIS 3 and I'm looking for an example of how I can change the widget type by using Python code. The change should be applied to fields of a vector layer.

In the end, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer and accept it, so other people looking for answer will more easily find it

Answer (score 1):

@user117572 answered to his/her own question:

> I found a solution which works:
>
> ```py
> setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('ValueMap', {'map': {u'Description 1': u'value1', u'Description 2': u'value2'}})
> layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(3, setup)
> ```